# How is the literal meaning of "rendezvous" related to its usage in distributed computing?

Tags: distributed-systems, communication-protocols

I am trying to figure out the difference between RPC and Rendezvous.  Is it correct that they differ only on their implementation on server side: RPC will involve creating a new process/thread to handle a request, and Rendezvous will pick an existing process/thread to handle a request?

The word "rendezvous" simply means a bunch of people meeting together. How is it related to its usage in computing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, the rendezvous would mean "a bunch of threads meeting together" instead of people. Rendezvous is a method of synchronisation in which at least two threads "meet". In other words, each thread that reaches the rendezvous point waits until all other threads have reached the same point before proceeding.

In the context of Distributed Algorithms the Rendezvous Problem is the task of devising an algorithm that will ensure that at least two entities (e.g., mobile agents) starting from different positions will meet after a finite amount of time in a specific environment (e.g., in a graph).

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean rendezvous mean the same as barrier? I heard that both rendezvous and RPC are remote operations, unrelated to barrier.

Comment: As far as I know rendezvous is the same as barrier, yes.